# Dismissible & extendable scroll view in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking for a way to achieve the effect shown below in React Native. I have already achieved the navigation bar and tab bar setup using React Navigation.

Now comes the part when I integrate a scroll like the one shown below. Effectively there is a view with lots of rows in it. I tried setting this up in a view wrapped in a `ScrollView` but this is too simplistic as the view just remains fixed on the screen and I'm looking to move the map with the view.

I'm looking for pseudocode if anything. Can anyone with experience in React Native suggest a good layout to achieve this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of fun with this. We could achieve the same effect by just creating a simple overlay on your map to display your list of services. The state of the overlay would be rendered visible from a callback on a button and rendered invisible by the 'refresh' or pull-down from an encapsulating `<ScrollView />`.

Here's what this component renders:

[image: It's working! It's working!]

Here's the component class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  Dimensions,
  RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';

export default class SO_MapOverlay extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            // Simple state variable to hide and show service list
            serviceListVisible: false,
            refreshing: false,
            data: [
                { key: 'item1' },
                { key: 'item2' },
                { key: 'item3' },
                { key: 'item4' },
                { key: 'item5' },
                { key: 'item6' },
                { key: 'item7' },
                { key: 'item8' }
            ],
        }
    }

    // Simply hides the button and shows the list overlay
    showRouteOverview() {
        this.setState({ serviceListVisible: true });
    }

    // Reverses showRouteOverview() when the user pulls down
    onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ refreshing: true });
        this.setState({ serviceListVisible: false });
        this.setState({ refreshing: false });
    }

    // Indicate the offset you want from the BOTTOM of the page
    renderSpacer(offset) {
        const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
        const spacerOffset = height - parseInt(offset);
        return (
            <View style={{ height: spacerOffset, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} />
        )
    }

    // Just renders each item in your flat list
    renderItem(itemData) {
        return(
            <View style={[styles.item]}>
                <Text style={{ color: 'black'}}>{itemData.item.key}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    renderRefreshControl() {
        return (
            <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this.onRefresh.bind(this)}
        // Note: I'm just hiding the activity monitor with these paramteres
          color='transparent'
          tintColor='transparent'
          />
        )
    }

    render() {
        const { serviceListVisible } = this.state;
        const listHeight = 56 * this.state.data.length;
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>I am map.</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={[styles.showRouteOverviewButton, serviceListVisible ? styles.invisible : null]}
                    onPress={() => { this.showRouteOverview() }}>
                    <Text>Show Services</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <ScrollView
                style={[styles.listContainer, serviceListVisible ? styles.visible : null ]}
                refreshControl={ this.renderRefreshControl() }>
                { this.renderSpacer(100) }
                <FlatList
                    style={[styles.list, { height: listHeight }]}
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={(itemData) => this.renderItem(itemData)}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                    />
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    visible: {
        display: 'flex'
    },
    invisible: {
        display: 'none'
    },
    mapContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
    },
    showRouteOverviewButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 40,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    listContainer: {
        display: 'none',
        flex: 1,
    },
    list: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },
    item: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Comment: Could you help me adapt this answer so that the user can still scroll the map, rather than disabling map movement altogether after pressing the button? (due to `flex 1` in the container)

Comment: I see. Here's a [mod to the code](https://pastebin.com/VPi05Pzx) that remove the invisible space covering the map and collapses all the content into one layer (i.e. users will still be able to interact with the top box. However, it'll be up to you and your charting library to get the map to stay static as you scroll ;)

Comment: Thanks again. Extremely helpful for someone new to React! I had written a really nice solution with CSS/JS but become obsolete when our company moved to RN.